# Get list of extensions with upgrades available (from command line)

Tags: api, extension, upgrade, drush

I would like to know if it is possible to use the command-line to get a list of extensions that have upgrades available. I want to then use that to run cvapi extension.download to install the updates.

In summary, I want to do the following:

1. Get list of extensions that need updating
2. run extension.download

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something cv (https://github.com/civicrm/cv) can or should do, but I don't see it in there yet.